# Find a Checkbox in JQuery with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, checkbox

I want to find if a checkbox exists in a web page while using NodeJS with JQuery (open to other suggestions), and I am have not been able to find the correct path to the checkboxes within the form.

Here is the code for the web page:

```
<form id="roombookingform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="gid" value="962"><fieldset class="s-lc-rm-cap-l-1"><legend><h2>IVC Library - Room 100E <small>Capacity: 1</small></h2></legend><div>Location: First floor

Room amenities: 
- one table, four chairs
- a white board*
- a tower fan

*Markers are available for checkout at the Circulation Desk</div><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789587">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789587" value="489789587" data-seq="2281101" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789587');">
                        8:00am - 8:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789587" id="sch489789587dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789587" id="t_sch489789587" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:00am - 8:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789588">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789588" value="489789588" data-seq="2281102" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789588');">
                        8:30am - 9:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789588" id="sch489789588dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789588" id="t_sch489789588" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:30am - 9:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789589">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789589" value="489789589" data-seq="2281103" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789589');">
                        9:00am - 9:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789589" id="sch489789589dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789589" id="t_sch489789589" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 9:00am - 9:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789590">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789590" value="489789590" data-seq="2281104" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789590');">
                        9:30am - 10:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789590" id="sch489789590dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789590" id="t_sch489789590" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 9:30am - 10:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789591">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789591" value="489789591" data-seq="2281105" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789591');">
                        10:00am - 10:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789591" id="sch489789591dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789591" id="t_sch489789591" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 10:00am - 10:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789592">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789592" value="489789592" data-seq="2281106" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789592');">
                        10:30am - 11:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789592" id="sch489789592dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789592" id="t_sch489789592" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 10:30am - 11:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789593">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789593" value="489789593" data-seq="2281107" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789593');">
                        11:00am - 11:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789593" id="sch489789593dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789593" id="t_sch489789593" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 11:00am - 11:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789594">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789594" value="489789594" data-seq="2281108" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789594');">
                        11:30am - 12:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789594" id="sch489789594dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789594" id="t_sch489789594" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 11:30am - 12:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789595">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789595" value="489789595" data-seq="2281109" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789595');">
                        12:00pm - 12:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789595" id="sch489789595dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789595" id="t_sch489789595" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 12:00pm - 12:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789596">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789596" value="489789596" data-seq="2281110" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789596');">
                        12:30pm - 1:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789596" id="sch489789596dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789596" id="t_sch489789596" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 12:30pm - 1:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789597">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789597" value="489789597" data-seq="2281111" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789597');">
                        1:00pm - 1:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789597" id="sch489789597dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789597" id="t_sch489789597" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 1:00pm - 1:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789598">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789598" value="489789598" data-seq="2281112" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789598');">
                        1:30pm - 2:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789598" id="sch489789598dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789598" id="t_sch489789598" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 1:30pm - 2:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789599">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789599" value="489789599" data-seq="2281113" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789599');">
                        2:00pm - 2:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789599" id="sch489789599dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789599" id="t_sch489789599" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 2:00pm - 2:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789600">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789600" value="489789600" data-seq="2281114" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789600');">
                        2:30pm - 3:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789600" id="sch489789600dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789600" id="t_sch489789600" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 2:30pm - 3:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789601">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789601" value="489789601" data-seq="2281115" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789601');">
                        3:00pm - 3:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789601" id="sch489789601dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789601" id="t_sch489789601" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 3:00pm - 3:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789602">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789602" value="489789602" data-seq="2281116" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789602');">
                        3:30pm - 4:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789602" id="sch489789602dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789602" id="t_sch489789602" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 3:30pm - 4:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789603">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789603" value="489789603" data-seq="2281117" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789603');">
                        4:00pm - 4:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789603" id="sch489789603dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789603" id="t_sch489789603" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 4:00pm - 4:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789604">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789604" value="489789604" data-seq="2281118" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789604');">
                        4:30pm - 5:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789604" id="sch489789604dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789604" id="t_sch489789604" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 4:30pm - 5:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789605">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789605" value="489789605" data-seq="2281119" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789605');">
                        5:00pm - 5:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789605" id="sch489789605dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789605" id="t_sch489789605" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 5:00pm - 5:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789606">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789606" value="489789606" data-seq="2281120" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789606');">
                        5:30pm - 6:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789606" id="sch489789606dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789606" id="t_sch489789606" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 5:30pm - 6:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789607">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789607" value="489789607" data-seq="2281121" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789607');">
                        6:00pm - 6:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789607" id="sch489789607dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789607" id="t_sch489789607" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 6:00pm - 6:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789608">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789608" value="489789608" data-seq="2281122" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789608');">
                        6:30pm - 7:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789608" id="sch489789608dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789608" id="t_sch489789608" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 6:30pm - 7:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789609">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789609" value="489789609" data-seq="2281123" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789609');">
                        7:00pm - 7:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789609" id="sch489789609dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789609" id="t_sch489789609" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 7:00pm - 7:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789610">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789610" value="489789610" data-seq="2281124" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789610');">
                        7:30pm - 8:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789610" id="sch489789610dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789610" id="t_sch489789610" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 7:30pm - 8:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789611">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789611" value="489789611" data-seq="2281125" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789611');">
                        8:00pm - 8:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789611" id="sch489789611dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789611" id="t_sch489789611" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:00pm - 8:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789612">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789612" value="489789612" data-seq="2281126" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789612');">
                        8:30pm - 9:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789612" id="sch489789612dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789612" id="t_sch489789612" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:30pm - 9:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><a href="#bform" class="sr-only">Skip to registration form</a></fieldset><fieldset class="s-lc-rm-cap-l-1"><legend><h2>IVC Library - Room 200G <small>Capacity: 1</small></h2></legend><div>Location: Second floor

Room amenities: 
- one table, four chairs
- a white board*
- a tower fan

*Markers are available for checkout at the Circulation Desk</div><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789613">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789613" value="489789613" data-seq="2282101" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789613');">
                        8:00am - 8:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789613" id="sch489789613dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789613" id="t_sch489789613" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 8:00am - 8:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789614">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789614" value="489789614" data-seq="2282102" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789614');">
                        8:30am - 9:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789614" id="sch489789614dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789614" id="t_sch489789614" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 8:30am - 9:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789615">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789615" value="489789615" data-seq="2282103" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789615');">
                        9:00am - 9:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789615" id="sch489789615dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789615" id="t_sch489789615" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 9:00am - 9:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789616">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789616" value="489789616" data-seq="2282104" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789616');">
                        9:30am - 10:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789616" id="sch489789616dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789616" id="t_sch489789616" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 9:30am - 10:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789617">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789617" value="489789617" data-seq="2282105" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789617');">
                        10:00am - 10:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789617" id="sch489789617dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789617" id="t_sch489789617" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 10:00am - 10:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789618">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789618" value="489789618" data-seq="2282106" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789618');">
                        10:30am - 11:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789618" id="sch489789618dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789618" id="t_sch489789618" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 10:30am - 11:00am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789619">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789619" value="489789619" data-seq="2282107" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789619');">
                        11:00am - 11:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789619" id="sch489789619dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789619" id="t_sch489789619" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 11:00am - 11:30am Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789620">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789620" value="489789620" data-seq="2282108" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789620');">
                        11:30am - 12:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789620" id="sch489789620dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789620" id="t_sch489789620" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 11:30am - 12:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789621">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789621" value="489789621" data-seq="2282109" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789621');">
                        12:00pm - 12:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789621" id="sch489789621dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789621" id="t_sch489789621" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 12:00pm - 12:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789622">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789622" value="489789622" data-seq="2282110" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789622');">
                        12:30pm - 1:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789622" id="sch489789622dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789622" id="t_sch489789622" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 12:30pm - 1:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789623">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789623" value="489789623" data-seq="2282111" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789623');">
                        1:00pm - 1:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789623" id="sch489789623dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789623" id="t_sch489789623" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 1:00pm - 1:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789624">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789624" value="489789624" data-seq="2282112" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789624');">
                        1:30pm - 2:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789624" id="sch489789624dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789624" id="t_sch489789624" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 1:30pm - 2:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789625">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789625" value="489789625" data-seq="2282113" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789625');">
                        2:00pm - 2:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789625" id="sch489789625dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789625" id="t_sch489789625" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 2:00pm - 2:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789626">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789626" value="489789626" data-seq="2282114" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789626');">
                        2:30pm - 3:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789626" id="sch489789626dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789626" id="t_sch489789626" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 2:30pm - 3:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789627">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789627" value="489789627" data-seq="2282115" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789627');">
                        3:00pm - 3:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789627" id="sch489789627dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789627" id="t_sch489789627" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 3:00pm - 3:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789628">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789628" value="489789628" data-seq="2282116" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789628');">
                        3:30pm - 4:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789628" id="sch489789628dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789628" id="t_sch489789628" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 3:30pm - 4:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789629">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789629" value="489789629" data-seq="2282117" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789629');">
                        4:00pm - 4:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789629" id="sch489789629dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789629" id="t_sch489789629" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 4:00pm - 4:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789630">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789630" value="489789630" data-seq="2282118" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789630');">
                        4:30pm - 5:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789630" id="sch489789630dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789630" id="t_sch489789630" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 4:30pm - 5:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789631">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789631" value="489789631" data-seq="2282119" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789631');">
                        5:00pm - 5:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789631" id="sch489789631dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789631" id="t_sch489789631" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 5:00pm - 5:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789632">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789632" value="489789632" data-seq="2282120" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789632');">
                        5:30pm - 6:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789632" id="sch489789632dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789632" id="t_sch489789632" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 5:30pm - 6:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789633">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789633" value="489789633" data-seq="2282121" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789633');">
                        6:00pm - 6:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789633" id="sch489789633dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789633" id="t_sch489789633" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 6:00pm - 6:30pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489789634">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489789634" value="489789634" data-seq="2282122" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489789634');">
                        6:30pm - 7:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489789634" id="sch489789634dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489789634" id="t_sch489789634" value="IVC Library - Room 200G 6:30pm - 7:00pm Tuesday, February 7, 2017"><a href="#bform" class="sr-only">Skip to registration form</a></fieldset>
```

Code above was cut short to fit but still give enough data.

Let's say I want to see if the checkbox with id sch489789587 exists (it's the first one in the form), how would I do that? I'm using something like this:

```
   if ($('#sch489789587 ').closest('roombookingform').find('input:checkbox').length > 0)
        console.log("Checkbox exists.");
```

EDIT:
NodeJS code running the above request:

```
require("jsdom").env("http://ivc.libcal.com/rooms_acc.php?gid=962&d=2017-02-10&cap=0", function (err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    if ($('#sch489789587').length > 0) {
        console.log('checkbox present')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check using

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('sch489789587dur');
if(checkbox){
      console.log('checkbox present');
}
```

also this worked fine for me

```
$('#roombookingform #sch489789587');
```

Make sure your code is inside ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkbox = $('#roombookingform #sch489789587');
if(checkbox.length){
      console.log('checkbox present');
}
```

To select a checkbox by value you can simply use

```
$('input[value="someValue"]')
```

checkout this link for reference:

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: can you share the code snippet please?
did you get any error in console.

Comment: I added an edit to my question showing what I'm using to run the JQuery command.

Comment: It still doesn't work, this is the website I'm trying to get the checkbox from: http://ivc.libcal.com/rooms_acc.php?gid=962&d=2017-02-07&cap=0

Comment: please try the edited code iit works fine in the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! Is there also a way to find a checkbox by it's value rather than ID?

Comment: yes there is a way for that. I would rather say there is a way for selecting elements by whichever attribute you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to check that an element exists you can use `.length` to check existence of elements.

```
if ($('#sch489789587').length > 0)
   console.log('Checkbox exists');
```

And if you want to see that first checkbox has the `id = 'sch489789587'` you can do this

```
if ($("#roombookingform").find("input[type=checkbox]").first().attr("id") == "sch489789587")
   console.log('first checkbox has id sch489789587');
```

Comment: I had tried the first one using length and it doesn't work... Can you see if I', using the right path? The form is from here: view-source:http://ivc.libcal.com/rooms_acc.php?gid=962&d=2017-02-07&cap=0

Comment: it is there run this in console `if ($('#sch489789587').length > 0) alert("exists");`

Comment: It doesn't work... I've added more of the code I am using in my question.

Comment: AT which time you execute this because once page is fully loaded than it will run correctly.

Comment: The code I added above is all I am using to pull it up.